# Integer executing as a string and not an integer?

Tags: java

When we are in a for loop,

```
for(int i =0; i< 10 ; i++)
{
   System.out.println(i + 1);
}
```

will execute 1-10

However, if I change `System.out.println` to lets say a function `passed` such as

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
passed( "Row" + (i+1));
}
```

Where passed is

```
public static void passed(String check) {

System.out.println(check + "Passed");
}
```

It executes

01 Passed
11 Passed
21 Passed
31 Passed....
41
51
61

and so forth

Can anyone explain why does it pass the value first and skip the math?

Comment: `"Row" + (i+1)` or `"Row" + i+1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java apply a particular rule when it comes to mixing `String` and any numerics (`int`, `double`, ...):

```
System.out.println(1+1+""); //prints 2
```

however

```
System.out.println(""+1+1);//prints 11
```

How's that ?

Java will read from right to left and give priority to `String`. So, in the first case Java will evaluate `int + int = int` before evaluating `int + String = String`. But in the second example, it will be `String + int = String` being first evaluated then `String + int = String`.

Comment: That is the coolest thing I've seen the whole day! Thanks for educating me

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(i + 1);       --> println(int) called
System.out.println(check + "Passed"); --> println(String) is called.
```

java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int check = 0;
    System.out.println(check + "Passed"); //StringBuilder operation int + string concatenated as Strings then println is called.
    System.out.println(check + 5); // int + int concatenated as int, then println is called 
}
```

byte code :

```
 0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   5:   new     #22; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   8:   dup
   9:   iload_1       
   10:  invokestatic    #24; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Str
ing;
    // use StringBuilder and invoke println()
   13:  invokespecial   #30; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/la
ng/String;)V
   16:  ldc     #33; //String Passed
   18:  invokevirtual   #35; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang
/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;  
   21:  invokevirtual   #39; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/l
ang/String;
   24:  invokevirtual   #43; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/St
ring;)V --> string println called
   27:  getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   30:  iload_1              // load value of check(int)
   31:  iconst_5           ---->  constant 5 
   32:  iadd               ----> add constant 5 and value of check and then invoke method
   33:  invokevirtual   #48; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V --> integer println called
   36:  return
```

Comment: I am passing passed( (i+1) ), shouldn't it do the math first?

Comment: @OctavianRox: I suggest posting a full example that exhibits the behavior -- it's not clear if you're doing something to cause it without realizing it.

Comment: @blackSmith -  Byte code on its way.. Sorry for the delay.. :P

Comment: Even without `println (int)` method, it would give the same result: `int -> (boxing) -> Integer <- Object`, while there is method `println (Object)`, which just runs `toString` on it.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg - Yes.. But `println(int)` is being called.

Comment: @OctavianRox - check the lines of code where I've marked `-->`. Couldn't cut-down on the byte-code.

Comment: Dont mind ignorance, but I am not really sure what a byte code is. So ill look at that first

Comment: Now that's a hell of an explanation. Withdrawn dislike.

Comment: @OctavianRox - The Java source code (.java file) when compiled generates a .class file (known as bytecode). This contains the code after the compiler has parsed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `System.out.println` directly, the run time can determine that the value being passed is an `int` and that addition should be performed before the `println`  (for `int` values) is executed. When you are wrapping that call up in a function which takes a `String` parameter and passing your `int` value into that function, the `int` value is being coerced into a `String` value as `passed` is called and then concatenation is being done instead of addition before the `println` (for `String` values) is executed.